# Почему в слове "портняжка" пишется буква Ж?

Tags: орфография, согласные

ПОРТНОЙ,  м. Специалист по шитью платья. **Портняжка,** -и; мн. род. -жек, дат. -жкам; м. Уничиж.

Слова "портняга" нет, суффикс ЯЖК тоже отсутствует.

Но почему-то такое написание кажется правильным, как и симпатичный ― симпатяшка, у которого больше оснований писаться через Ж (существует слово *симпатяга*).

Comment: Оппаньки, как говаривает Веллер. Дополняю ответ!)))

Comment: Уж очень часто переформулируется вопрос. Не буду корректировать ответ, но "-га" здесь ни при чём. Портня**ж**ить, а не "портнячить(шить)"! Подтяжка тоже не от "-ги". Не существует надёжного пути от академических обобщений, даже если они идут от Лопатина. Механизм верного решения заложен в голове наблюдательного носителя языка, надо просто в ней порыться :).

Comment: Подтяжка именно от "-ги". Она подтяГИвает.

Comment: @Alex_ander *...надо просто в ней [голове носителя] порыться* — это методология так называемой "народной этимологии". Она не гарантирует на 100% правильного ответа.

Comment: Этот подход с этимологией вообще не связан.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть глагол:

ПОРТНЯ́ЖИТЬ, портняжу, портняжишь, несовер. Заниматься ремеслом портного (прост.).
|| Шить, чинить платье (разг. шутл.).

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Comment: А какова схема образования слова: (1) портной - портняжить - портняжка или (2) портной - портняжка.  По смыслу подходит второй вариант.

Comment: Уверена, что портняжить - портняжка. Он чем занимается? - Портняжит. - А, портняжка!

Comment: Судя по всему, всё проще: "портняга — портняжить", "портняга — портняжка". Ссылки на источники в моём ответе.

Comment: Всё может быть! Главное, что мы написание Ж объяснили).

Answer (score 3):

А тут у нас два суффикса - **яж** и **к**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. [Русские слова с суффиксом -яж](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D1%8F%D0%B6):

- бродяжка
- дворняжка
- [симпатяжка](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- тюряжка

---

Дополнение после коммента:

[портняга](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B0) существует!

Да здавствует ВМПС им Тургенева!

(Василий Аксенов.

...Поневоле преисполнишься гордости за ВМПС им. Тургенева, как иные писатели ернически называют наш «великий-могучий-правдивый-свободный».)

**[ПОРТНЯГА](https://slovar.cc/rus/tolk/86106.html)**

> *м. разг.-сниж.*
>
> Неискусный портной.

Большой современный толковый словарь русского языка. 2012

---

[ПОРТНЯГА](http://www.ubrus.org/dictionary-units/?id=111501),

> портняги, *м. (простореч. пренебр.)*. Портной.

Толковый словарь русского языка Д. Н. Ушакова

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все Ваши примеры относятся к чередованию г/ж в суффиксе **-яг**. В вопросе специально акцентируется внимание на отсутствие слова "портняга".

Comment: А я его запросто придумаю и употреблю. И это будет в рамках русского словообразования. У К. Чуковского: лога - это такая очень большая ложка.

Comment: Хорошо бы тогда обозначить прямо в ответе, что в слове "портняжка" суффикс "яж" происходит от "яг" в придуманном Вами "портняга".

Comment: Я погуглила - слово зафиксировано! А "выдумала" я, не знаючи, существующее.

Comment: Да, я тоже нашёл источники. Теперь всё сходится. Просто для меня правильная логика важнее правильно угаданного ответа :)

Comment: Гриззлик, ну что ты такое говоришь! Я именно правильно логиковала (логикничала, логижничила), а не угадывала! )))

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл в этимологическом словаре Черных, что слово "портняжить" образовано от "портняга". Следовательно, последнее вышло из употребления в языке, а "портняжить" осталось. "Портняжка" по инерции числится уничижительным, хотя уничижительность эту вряд ли ощущают носители языка, не сталкивавшиеся с "портными" делами в таких тонкостях, но читавшие в детстве сказку братьев Гримм "Храбрый портняжка".

Comment: Не только у Черных - в трёх словарях, и 2012 года тоже: не - "вышло из употребления в языке"!)))